# What is the "New Theological Movement" within the Catholic Church?

Tags: catholicism, movements

I've only seen 4 links so far to posts from  http://newtheologicalmovement.blogspot.com on this site, but all it appears to be is a blog by a priest with a [very staunch detractor](http://newtheologicalmovement.blogspot.com) who comes up with explanations to things that otherwise aren't answered explicitly in the Catechism like [does Jesus know what God knows](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/q/2711/4).

So, is the priest who blogs there (Fr. Ryan Erlenbush) a priest in good standing in his diocese and does he have any credentials as a Theologigian.

Like Chesterton, I am rather of an older fashion and usually skeptical of anything that has the words "new" and "theology" that close together. So, if someone could shed some light on this "movement", it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

This "New Theological Movement" seems to be something specific to Fr. Ryan Erlenbush.

There is a movement called New Theology (*Nouvelle Théologie*), whose tenets were condemned in Pope Pius XII's encyclical [*Humani Generis*](http://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-xii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xii_enc_12081950_humani-generis.html). See:

- [*Nouvelle Théologie New Theology: Inheritor of Modernism, Precursor of Vatican II*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=3035) (2010) by Jürgen Mettepenningen
- "[The structure of the encyclical *Humani Generis*](http://scholastic.us.to/hg_gl.html)" by [Reginald Garrigou-Lagrange, O.P.](http://www.christendom-awake.org/pages/thomas-crean/saint-in-heaven.htm)

  - To the question "[Where is the New Theology Leading Us?](https://archive.org/stream/Garrigou-LagrangeEnglish/_Where%20is%20the%20New%20Theology%20Leading%20Us__%20-%20Garrigou-Lagrange,%20Reginald,%20O.P_#page/n0)", Fr. Garrigou-Lagrange responded: back to [Modernism](http://www.papalencyclicals.net/Pius10/p10pasce.htm).

There is also a movement called the New Theological Movement, which began in the early 20<sup>th</sup> century as a movement to educate the faithful about the Holy Mass, but in the years leading up to Vatican II, it was hijacked by [Modernists](http://www.papalencyclicals.net/Pius10/p10pasce.htm) who wanted to change the Mass (dumb it down) to accommodate "modern man". The [New Theological Movement](http://www.newliturgicalmovement.org/) today has returned to the movement's original intentions.