# What is the connection of Alta Vendita in the present Church Crisis regarding homosexual scandal & cover-up?

Tags: catholicism, freemasonry

> The Permanent Instruction of the Alta Vendita (commonly called the
>   Alta Vendita) is a document, originally published in Italian in 1859,
>   purportedly produced by the highest lodge of the Italian Carbonari
>   and written by "Piccolo Tigre" ("Little Tiger"), which, according to
>   George F. Dillon, was supposedly the pseudonym of a Jewish
>   Freemason.
>
> The document details an alleged Masonic plan to infiltrate the
>   Catholic Church and spread liberal ideas within it. The Carbonari had
>   strong similarities to Freemasonry and so the document is seen by some
>   as a Masonic document. In the 19th century, Pope Pius IX and Pope
>   Leo XIII both asked for it to be published. It was first published by
>   Jacques Crétineau-Joly in his book L'Église romaine en face de la
>   Révolution in 1859. It was popularised in the English speaking world
>   by Monsignor George F. Dillon in 1885 with his book the War of
>   Anti-Christ with the Church and Christian Civilization.
>
> It is still circulated by many traditionalist and sedevacantist
>   Catholics, who believe it accurately describes the changes in the
>   church in the post-Vatican II era.
>
> ([Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alta_Vendita))

What is the connection of Alta Vendita in the present Church Crisis regarding homosexual scandal & cover-up involving clergy & prelates?

Comment: Why do you think that there is a connection at all?

Answer (score 4):

These recent homosexual/pederast scandals are an end-result of at least 1½ centuries of infiltration and moral and doctrinal corruption of the Church by [Freemasonry](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/09771a.htm) and Communism.

<sup>Freemasonry is the most-condemned heresy of all times. 17 papal documents from Clement XII (1783) until Leo XIII (1890) have explicitly condemned it. [Several popes have also condemned Communism and Socialism.](https://www.tfpstudentaction.org/blog/what-the-popes-really-say-about-socialism) Catholics are forbidden to be Freemasons; see: [Declaration on Masonic Associations Nov 26, 1983](http://www.vatican.va/roman_curia/congregations/cfaith/documents/rc_con_cfaith_doc_19831126_declaration-masonic_en.html).</sup>

## Timeline of the Freemason's infiltration/corruption

### 1859-1884

The "*Permanent Instruction of the* Alta Vendita [*Masonic High Lodge*]" is a leaked document that Pius IX (who guaranteed this document's authenticity in his [brief of 25 Feb. 1861](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5478)) and Leo XIII asked to be published. Pope Leo XIII subsequently wrote the encyclical [*Humanum Genus*](http://w2.vatican.va/content/leo-xiii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_l-xiii_enc_18840420_humanum-genus.html) condemning Freemasonry in 1884, urging everyone "to tear away the mask from Freemasonry, and to let it be seen as it really is" (§31).

The *Permanent Instruction* is printed in [**chapter 14**](https://archive.org/stream/warofantichristw00dillrich#page/n91) of Msgr. Dillon's [*Grand Orient Freemasonry Unmasked*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=2836) (originally titled: *The War of Antichrist with the Church and Christian Civilization* ([audiobook](https://librivox.org/the-war-of-antichrist-with-the-church-and-christian-civilization-by-george-f-dillon/))); [**chapter 15**](https://archive.org/stream/warofantichristw00dillrich#page/n99) is the letter by Piccolo Tigre.*

<sup>*[Giuseppe Mazzini](https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Encyclopedia_Americana_(1920)/Mazzini,_Giuseppe), a member of the Italian Freemasons called the [Carbonari](https://archive.org/stream/warofantichristw00dillrich#page/n89) and key figure, along with Garibaldi et al., in the Freemasonry-driven unification movement of Italy</sup>

The following is an excerpt from the *Permanent Instruction*, quoted in John Vennari's [*The Permanent Instruction of the Alta Vendita: A Masonic Blueprint for the Subversion of the Catholic Church*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=4568):

> The Pope, whoever he is, will never come to the secret societies; it is up to the secret societies to take the first step toward the Church, with the aim of conquering both of them.
>
> The task that we are going to undertake is not the work of a day, or of a month, or of a year; it may last several years, perhaps a century; but in our ranks the soldier dies and the struggle goes on.
>
> We do not intend to win the Popes to our cause, to make them neophytes of our principles, propagators of our ideas. That would be a ridiculous dream; and if events turn out in some way, if Cardinals or prelates, for example, of their own free will or by surprise, should enter into a part of our secrets, this is not at all an incentive for desiring their elevation to the See of Peter. That elevation would ruin us. Ambition alone would have led them to apostasy, the requirements of power would force them to sacrifice us. What we must ask for, what we should look for and wait for, as the Jews wait for the Messiah, is *a Pope according to our needs ...*
>
> With that we shall march more securely towards the assault on the Church than with the pamphlets of our brethren in France and even the gold of England. Do you want to know the reason for this? It is that with this, in order to shatter the high rock on which God has built His Church, we no longer need Hannibalian vinegar, or need gunpowder, or even need our arms. We have the little finger of the successor of Peter engaged in the ploy, and this little finger is as good, for this crusade, as all the Urban II’s and all the Saint Bernards in Christendom.
>
> We have no doubt that we will arrive at this supreme end of our efforts. But when? But how? The unknown is not yet revealed. Nevertheless, as nothing should turn us aside from the plan drawn up, and on the contrary everything should tend to this, as if as early as tomorrow success were going to crown the work that is barely sketched, we wish, in this instruction, which will remain secret for the mere initiates, to give the officials in the charge of the supreme **Vente** [Freemasonic lodge] some advice that they should instill in all the brethren, in the form of instruction or of a memorandum ...
>
> Now then, to assure ourselves a Pope of the required dimensions, it is a question first of *shaping him ... for this Pope, a generation worthy of the reign we are dreaming of.* Leave old people and those of a mature age aside; go to the youth, and if it is possible, even to the children ... You will contrive for yourselves, at little cost, a reputation as good Catholics and pure patriots.
>
> This reputation will put access to our doctrines into the midst of the young clergy, as well as deeply into the monasteries. In a few years, by the force of things, this young clergy will have overrun all the functions; they will form the sovereign’s council, they will be called to choose a Pontiff who should reign. *And this Pontiff, like most of his contemporaries, will be necessarily more or less imbued with the* Italian and *humanitarian principles that we are going to begin to put into circulation*. It is a small grain of black mustard that we are entrusting to the ground; but the sunshine of justice will develop it up to the highest power, and you will see one day what a rich harvest this small seed will produce.
>
> In the path that we are laying out for our brethren, there are found great obstacles to conquer, difficulties of more than one kind to master. They will triumph over them by experience and by clearsightedness; but the goal is so splendid that it is important to put all the sails to the wind in order to reach it. You want to revolutionize Italy, look for the Pope whose portrait we have just drawn. You wish to establish the reign of the chosen ones on the throne of the prostitute of Babylon, *let the Clergy march under your standard, always believing that they are marching under the banner of the apostolic keys*. You intend to make the last vestige of tyrants and the oppressors disappear; lay your snares like Simon Bar-Jona; lay them in the sacristies, the seminaries, and the monasteries rather than at the bottom of the sea: and if you do not hurry, we promise you a catch more miraculous than his. The fisher of fish became the fisher of men; you will bring friends around the apostolic Chair. You will have preached a *revolution in tiara and in cope, marching with the cross and the banner*, a revolution that will need to be only a little bit urged on to set fire to the four corners of the world.

Piccolo Tigre's letter is also important because he realizes that the Catholic Church cannot be destroyed, as had been the Freemasons' plan previously; their goal now is to corrupt the Church for their own purposes, primarily by a recruiting strategy that divides husbands from their wives and families and forces them to take secret oaths even their wives cannot know.

Here is one example of where the "Little Tiger" describes their plan to corrupt the Church ([Dillon p. 82](https://archive.org/stream/warofantichristw00dillrich#page/82)):

> It is corruption *en masse* that we have undertaken: the corruption of the people by the clergy, and the corruption of the clergy by ourselves; the corruption which ought, one day to enable us to put the Church in her tomb. I have recently heard one of our friends, laughing in a philosophic manner at our projects, say to us: "in order to destroy Catholicism it is necessary to commence by suppressing woman." The words are true in a sense; but since we cannot suppress woman, let us corrupt her with the Church, *corruptio optimi pessima* [the corruption of the best is the worst]. The object we have in view is sufficiently good to tempt men such as we are; let us not separate ourselves from it for some miserable personal satisfaction of vengeance. The best poniard with which to strike the Church is corruption. To work, then, even to the very end.

### 1907

This corruption has even reached the levels of high-ranking clergy in the Church, perverting doctrine with the errors of [Modernism](http://modernism.us.to/), "the synthesis of all heresies", as Pope St. Pius X called it in his 1907 encyclical condemning Modernism, [*Pascendi Dominici gregis*](http://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-x/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-x_enc_19070908_pascendi-dominici-gregis.html) (cf. also his 1907 list of condemned errors [*Lamentabili sane*](http://www.papalencyclicals.net/Pius10/p10lamen.htm)).

<sup>The philosophical/doctrinal corruption began even with Kant, who, [like Luther](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/57086/1787) and the Freemasons, [also despised the great *Summa Theologica* of St. Thomas Aquinas](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/33302/1787).</sup>

### 1950

Modernism resurfaced on the eve of the Second Vatican Council, under the name of [New Theology (*Nouvelle Théologie*)](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/66259/1787), provoking Pope Pius XII to condemn its philosophical and theological errors in his 1950 encyclical [*Humani Generis*](http://w2.vatican.va/content/pius-xii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_p-xii_enc_12081950_humani-generis.html).

## Communist infiltration into seminaries

Another aspect is the Communist infiltration into seminaries. [Bella Dodd](https://youtu.be/37HgRWTsGs0) was a spy who revealed this strategy of corruption.

Chapter 18 "Twentieth Century Harbingers" (pp. 1089-1128) of [*The Rite of Sodomy: Homosexuality and the Roman Catholic Church*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_list&search=title:%22The%20Rite%20of%20Sodomy:%20Homosexuality%20and%20the%20Roman%20Catholic%20Church%22&sort=timestamp.asc) (vol. 5) by [Randy Engel](http://newengelpublishing.com),* the leading historian on homosexuality/pederasty in the modern United States Catholic Church, does a good job reviewing the Communist infiltration and corruption of morals.

<sup>*[Her recent articles](https://akacatholic.com/author/guest-contributor/) on the Cdl. Viganò affair, etc., can be found on [AKA Catholic](https://akacatholic.com/author/guest-contributor/).</sup>

---

<sup>**February 2019 update:**
It has been revealed that [disgraced homosexual Cdl. McCarrick associated with the Communist training center in St. Gallen, Switzerland](https://www.churchmilitant.com/news/article/vatican-sex-summit-report), which would become the seat of the "St. Gallen Mafia," a group of liberals who opposed Benedict XVI in the 2005 conclave and campaigned for Francis's election in 2013 (cf. ch. 1 of [*The Dictator Pope*](https://isidore.co/calibre#panel=book_details&book_id=6799)).</sup>

Comment: This is not your first answer that makes me think that you belong to one of these extremely conservative groups within the church. If my observation is right: Why do you always believe in such conspiracy theories?

Comment: @MartinRosenau It's not a theory. The facts are there for everyone to see. The popes themselves frequently speak of conspiracies against the Church (cf. the popes' quotes [here](https://novusordowatch.org/2018/08/conspiracy-catholic-church-true-popes-speak/)); e.g., Pope Leo XIII in his encyclical against Freemasonry, [_Humanum Genus_](http://w2.vatican.va/content/leo-xiii/en/encyclicals/documents/hf_l-xiii_enc_18840420_humanum-genus.html) §4, writes:

Comment: @MartinRosenau "The Roman Pontiffs Our predecessors, in their incessant watchfulness over the safety of the Christian people, were prompt in detecting the presence and the purpose of this capital enemy immediately it sprang into the light instead of hiding as a dark **conspiracy**; and , moreover, they took occasion with true foresight to give, as it were on their guard, and not allow themselves to be caught by the devices and snares laid out to deceive them."

Comment: This is not what I'm talking about. Surely there are a lot of groups and people who want to  damage the Church. However I have the impression that may conservative Catholics often blame people not having their own opinion whenever there are problems in the Church. For example they claim that the Vaticanum II is the reason of many problems in the Church which can be proven to have begun no later than 1920...