# Is it to say: "We can have reasonable hope that all will be saved" heretical?

Tags: catholicism, hell, universalism

Unfortunately, we can hear some lay Catholics (sometimes even a bishop) say that: "We can have reasonable hope that all will be saved". It seems obvious that the statement is untrue, however, is it a heretical statement? And would for example bishop who persists in this error becomes a formal heretic?

We know that the Church [condemned](http://www.newadvent.org/fathers/3812.htm) the following proposition:

> If anyone says or thinks that the punishment of demons and of impious
>   men is only temporary, and will one day have an end, and that a
>   restoration (ἀποκατάστασις) will take place of demons and of impious
>   men, let him be anathema.

It seems that corollary of this statement is:

Corollary: **Punishments of impious men will never end.**

Imagine now that the statement: "We can have reasonable hope that all will be saved" is true. However, if the hope were to be reasonable, then the object of hope should be really possible, namely, it should be really possible that all are saved. But if all were saved, then the previous corollary would really be attributing some property to an empty set and then the condemnation would be [vacuously true](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vacuous_truth). But the opposite of the corollary would also be true (because we can attribute anything to an empty set, see a previous link to "Vacuous truth") in that case. Therefore, the case where all are saved seems logically inconsistent if we want to say that condemnation can not be empty.

Edit. My question is not duplicate. I am not searching an answer to a viewpoint on universal salvation, but I explicitly deny that as untrue. I am searching for what kind (degree) of error is to hold universal salvation (or rather, that "we can have reasonable hope that all will be saved").

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98593/discussion-on-question-by-thom-is-it-to-say-we-can-have-reasonable-hope-that-a).

Comment: In this video you can listen to exactly what bishop Barron said https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dmsa0sg4Od4

Answer (score 1):

## Doctrinal Universalism

Barron professes the heresy of [doctrinal universalism](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=37000),

> The theory that hell is essentially a kind of purgatory in which sins are expiated, so that eventually everyone will be saved. Also called *apokatastasis* [ἀποκατάστασις], it was condemned by the church in A.D. 543, against the Origenists, who claimed that
>
> > the punishment of devils and wicked men is temporary and will eventually cease, that is to say, that devils or the ungodly will be completely restored to their original state
>
> ([Denzinger 4](http://denzinger.patristica.net/denzinger/#n400)11).

## Balthasar & Barron believe hell is empty.

The [Modernist](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/72030/1787), [syncretist](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=36753), [New Theologian](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/66259/1787) [Hans Urs Von Balthasar](http://www.sspxasia.com/Documents/SiSiNoNo/1994_February/They_Think_Theyve_Won_PartIV.htm) (1905-1988), influenced by the fake mystic [Adrienne von Speyr](http://www.sspxasia.com/Documents/SiSiNoNo/1994_February/They_Think_Theyve_Won_PartIV.htm), promoted the heresy that hell is empty. He also wrote the [afterword of a book on Tarot cards and the occult](https://books.google.com/books?id=DR_IAgAAQBAJ&pg=PT1191).

Barron wrote the preface to the 2<sup>nd</sup> edition of Balthasar's [*Dare We Hope That All Men Be Saved*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fyJ_EX1UPtA).

## One cannot hope for the impossible.

The [intellectual virtue of faith](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS004.html#SSQ4A2THEP1) precedes the virtue of hope, [which exists in the will](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS018.html#SSQ18A1THEP1), since the intellect precedes the will (cf. 21<sup>st</sup> [Thomistic thesis](http://scholastic.us.to/24Thomisticpart2.htm)). The object of hope cannot contradict reason.

Discussing how faith precedes hope in [*Summa Theologica* II-II q. 17 a. 7](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/SS/SS017.html#SSQ17A7THEP1) co., St. Thomas Aquinas writes:

> the object of hope is a future good, arduous but **possible** to obtain
> <sub>Obiectum enim spei est bonum futurum arduum **possibile** haberi.</sub>

Thus, one cannot hope for impossible things, e.g., that God doesn't exist, that He contradict Himself, that the Church's dogmas change, that 2+2=5, etc.

## Religious Indifferentism

Related to his [universalist heresy](https://www.catholicculture.org/culture/library/dictionary/index.cfm?id=37000), Barron professes the heresy of [religious indifferentism](https://www.papalencyclicals.net/pius09/p9syll.htm), which holds that no one religion is necessary for salvation. Recently, [he told a Jew that Jesus is the "privileged way" of salvation](https://www.lifesitenews.com/blogs/is-jesus-christ-the-privileged-way-to-salvationor-the-only-way), which implies there are other means of salvation, directly contradicting, e.g., [Acts 4:12](http://drbo.org/cgi-bin/d?b=drl&bk=51&ch=4&l=12-#x) ("Neither is there salvation in any other. For there is no other name under heaven given to men, whereby we must be saved.").

## Hell exists, and its punishments are perpetual.

Athanasian Creed ([D](http://denzinger.patristica.net/denzinger/#n1) 40):

> those who have done good, will go into life everlasting, but those who have done evil, into **eternal** fire
>
> <sup>qui bona egerunt, ibunt in vitam æternam, qui vero mala, in ignem **æternum**</sup>

The Fourth Lateran Council (1215) defined the dogma that the rejected will receive ([D 4](http://denzinger.patristica.net/denzinger/#n400)29):

> **everlasting** punishment with the devil
>
> <sup>cum diabolo pœnam **perpetuam**</sup>

Once a soul is damned, there is no hope that it will be saved.

These dogmas are *de fide* ("of the faith"). [Contradicting a *de fide* truth incurs the censure of heresy; the effects of denying it are](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/a/55362/1787):

> Mortal sin committed directly against the virtue of faith, and, if the heresy is outwardly professed, excommunication is automatically incurred and membership of the Church forfeited.

Comment: So the conclusion is that it would be heretical to say such a statement? So, we can have reasonable certainty (based on his words) to believe that someone like Barron is excommunicated?

Comment: @Thom Yes, he's incurred automatic excommunication because he's outwardly professed heresy, but he'd need to be canonically tried for heresy before he can be deposed and his see declared vacant (cf. St. Robert Bellarmine [_On the Roman Pontiff_](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=5349); he mentions the deposition of the heretical bishop [Nestorius](http://www.newadvent.org/cathen/10755a.htm) _passim_).

Comment: How does the section on indifferentism help answer the question?

Comment: The bishop OP refers to says “ we can have reasonable hope” that all will be saved. That is in harmony with definition of love in 1cor 13:7 “ love...... hopes all things..,.. “.  One can hope for something while being aware that it cannot/will not  come true.

Comment: @Kris "_One can hope for something while being aware that it cannot/will not come true._" Can I hope for impossible things like that God doesn't exist, 2+2=5, etc.? See the added section: "One cannot hope for the impossible."

Comment: @MattGutting Religious indifferentism (that no one religion is necessary for salvation) is related to his doctrinal universalism. His mentor, von Balthasar, was also a promoter of false ecumenism / religious indifferentism / syncretism.

Comment: @Geremia Considering your answer about reasonable hope and combining with St. Thomas Reply 1 to [Q19A6](http://www.newadvent.org/summa/1019.htm#article6), am I right to conclude that even though God antecedently will all men to be saved we **cannot** have reasonable hope for the same precisely because God also consequently will some to be damned?  I'm trying to understand what "reasonable hope" means.  Example: if I don't know whether my neighbor will be saved (because I'm not omniscient), can I still wish that he will be, keeping in mind that God may consequently will him to be damned?

Comment: Maybe what's at issue here is how the word "hope" in popular usage has been polluted to mean "wish".  Mentally, I try to use "hope" for what is **certain** in the end (thus it involves some trust in God making it happen), and "wish" to mean my subjective desire while maintaining that this wish may not come true in the end.  Applying it to salvation that means we cannot hope for our neighbor to be saved while we still can wish for the best for our neighbor to be saved.  But for sure, hell **WILL** have some occupants, we as humans just don't know yet right now who will be in them.

Comment: @Geremia Your answer only gives reasons for "Once a soul is damned, there is no hope that it will be saved.". But the quetion is "Is someone damned / does a impious man exist?" You only give *ad personam* arguments against Hans Urs von Balthasar.

Comment: @Geremia Yes. There are some unrealated things in addition, but nothing I see answers the question. Please point me to the argument.

Comment: @K-HB Do you deny that Balthasar and Barron profess universalism? Balthasar's book even has an epilogue on apokatastasis, defending Origen, and other sections where he doubts the perpetuity of the punishments of hell.

Comment: @Geremia I don't know what Balthasar wrote. In your answer you only write "promoted the heresy that hell is empty", whithout specification of his statement or any citation. If Balthasar professes universalism (with your definition), this does not help answering the question.

Comment: please chat in [chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/98593/discussion-on-question-by-thom-is-it-to-say-we-can-have-reasonable-hope-that-a)